# Update field's rows with a value of dictionary

Tags: arcpy, update, dictionary, value-list

I'm new in programming and I'm struggling with my code. I have a dictionnary of districts and communities for each, like this:

```
MyDict = defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {u'DISTRICT': set([u'community1', u'community2']),
u'DISTRICT2': set([u'community3', u'community6'])})
```

Now I want to add the list of values in a shapefile of districts, in the row corresponding to the right district: so the field in this shapefile called 'District' has to be the same as the key of my dictionary if I understood well.
Expected result in shp:

```
<District>   |   <Communities>              |
DISTRICT     |   community1, community2     |
DISTRCIT2    |   community3, community6     |
```

My code isn't working, I get no error message but nothing written in the expected field:

```
Communities = ['Communities']           #field to be written with values
District = ['District']                 # field with district in the shp

# Update in the communities field of the Districts shapefile
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(MyDistrictShapefile, Communities) as cursor1:
for newRow in cursor1:

  # Define a loop pour all the district name in the shapefile
  districtsLoop = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(MyDistrictShapefile, District)]

  # Looking for the same district as the key and update the communities field
  if str(districtsLoop[0]) == str(myDict.keys()) :
     newRow[0] = myDict[str(districtsLoop[0])]
  cursor1.updateRow(newRow)
```

Anyone has an idea of how I can solve my problem? It's my first code and I don't see how to fix this.

Comment: try to indentent: for newRow in cursor1 and the following lines

Answer (score 2):

I dont understand all of your code but i'll give some parts of it a try: Why do you need a searchcursor inside the updatecursor when you already have created a Dictionary?

You should also need both fields (district and Community) in the updatecursor. District for use in the Dictionary and Community which you will calculate.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(MyDistrictShapefile, ['District','Communities']) as cursor1:
    for newRow in cursor1:
        try:
            row[1]=MyDict[row[0]]
            cursor1.updateRow(newRow)
        else:
            pass
```